# Updating a column based off records from two tables matching?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We're using SQL Server 2016. I have two tables, `DEAD` and `QUETABLE`. However, `QUETABLE` also has a column called `DEAD`. This is going to sound confusing, but I'll try to make it make sense. What I need to do, is set the column (`DEAD`) in `QUETABLE` to the value `YES` if the column `WEBSITE` in `QUETABLE` matches the same named column `WEBSITE` in the table `DEAD`.

*(The `DEAD` table is just filled with dead websites, `QUETABLE` might have some that are dead, marking it will let us know)*

In a magical world, something like this would work:

```
UPDATE QUETABLE 
SET [DEAD] = 'YES' 
WHERE
    SELECT de.website, de.[city], de.[state], de.[zip], de.[new-ind], de.phone
    FROM [QUETABLE] de
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT website, company, zip
                  FROM dead d2
                  WHERE d2.website = de.website OR d2.state = de.state OR d2.zip = de.zip)
```

But obviously that can't happen, and I can't really figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
UPDATE de
    SET [DEAD] = 'YES'
FROM [QUETABLE] de
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT website, company, zip
              FROM dead d2
              WHERE d2.website = de.website OR d2.state = de.state OR d2.zip = de.zip
             );
```

Comment: OHHHH, I thought I would have to select the tables in QUETABLE first. You're right! Thank you, I feel so silly -_-!

Comment: @Natsu . . . For `'YES'` you want exists.  Your text only mentions `website`, but presumably you want the same check on the other columns.

Comment: Ohh, I realize what I did wrong. My results came out way unexpected so I doubted myself. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I can't ask another question for 90mins, but I'm having a sort of relevant problem, if you can help I would apprecaite it! Question here: https://pastebin.com/XEzBibJs . I tried setting the NULL values to something else, but it didn't work either (no changes) with "SET [USED] = 'NULL' where [USED] != 'YES'"

Comment: @Natsu . . . The problem in that question -- as you have surmised -- are the `NULL` values.  They fail `<>` as well as `=`.

Comment: I forgot about "IS NULL", I'm still not fully there withi SQL queries. Thanks!